# @AppStorage variables in multiple struct instances

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

When using `@AppStorage`, you must pass in a unique key that will be used to access/decode the variable whenever you use it. This is reflected in the code below, in which increasing the `num` of one instance of a struct increases the `num` of another instance, because they both have the same `@AppStorage` key. So, I'm just wondering what the best way to go about using `@AppStorage` as a variable in a re-used struct is, or if this shouldn't even be done at all.

```
struct TestUI: View {
    
    @State var v1 = MyStruct()
    @State var v2 = MyStruct()
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(String(v1.num))
                    .onTapGesture { v1.num += 1 }
                
                Text(String(v2.num))
                    .onTapGesture { v2.num += 1 }
            }
        }
}

struct MyStruct {
    @AppStorage("num") var num: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: It seems you just misuse AppStorage, it is just a thing wrapper around UserDefaults - just persistent key/value pair, reuse or location of call does not matter here at all.

Comment: @Asperi  Right, but if I'm trying to create a separate value, stored in UserDefaults, for each instance of a class, how should I do this assuming there will be multiple class instances.